# Unsupported platform for fsevents error on installing Angular cli

Tags: node.js, angular

I encountered the following error in installing Angular.

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3  (node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents):

npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

When I use the **ng -v** command, it displays a message that does not recognize this command

```
The program 'ng' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install ng-common
```

OS: Linux mint 18.3

nodejs version 9.3.0

Help me please

Comment: Those are warnings, not errors, and they're not related to `ng` not being available.

Comment: Which command did you use to install angular cli?

Comment: npm install -g @angular/cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem like this:

Path known
Assuming you have a global modules set up for npm (by default ~/.node_modules_global)

```
$ npm prefix -g
```

Now set the path of modules/bin to our bash path environment to access over terminal

```
$ echo -e "export PATH=$(npm prefix -g)/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc 
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

How about setting a new one!

```
$ mkdir ~/path/module
$ npm config set prefix '~/path/module'
$ sudo chown -R $USER <directory>
```

Now the final touch, install angular/cli package

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

reference: [github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7735)

Answer (score 1):

and the I used this command:

```
npm install --no-optional -g @angular/cli
```

and output is like this:

```
/home/user/.npm-global/bin/ng -> /home/user/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
npm WARN sass-loader@6.0.6 requires a peer of node-sass@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```